Why regular languages closed under this operation?
Assume we apply the following operation on the regular language $L$:
$$OP(L)=\{a_2a_1a_4a_3\dots a_{2n}a_{2n-1}:a_1a_2a_3\dots a_{2n}\in L\}$$
Why $OP(L)$ remains regular?
I think this is as the same as shuffle but I have no idea to show that.

Make a DFA $D$ for language $L$.
Now make a copy $D'$ of this DFA, but only of the states, removing the transitions.
To add back transitions we check for all possible symbols $a, b$ for all possible pairs of states $x, y$ if $\delta(\delta(x, a), b) = y$ in $D$. If so, we add a new non-accepting state $s'$ to $D'$, and the transitions $\delta(x', b) = s'$, $\delta(s', a) = y'$.
We've now ensured that $D'$ recognizes $a_2a_1a_4a_3\dots$ iff $D$ recognizes $a_1a_2a_3a_4$, thus $OP(L)$ must also be regular.
